# how to catch an internal error from threads I have no control over?

Tags: multithreading, exception, websocket, racket

I'm using the web sockets library from racket, and my use case requires to maintain permanent connections, so I frequently establish new connections when the server closes one, the thing is that after some time the server spontaneously raises an internal error saying that an attempt to reschedule a dead thread was made, but the exception raises from within another thread that is not the main one, I want to catch that kind of error/exception that comes from other threads I have no direct control over as I really don't have time to hack and fix whatever happens in the library.

Comment: The approach of putting a band-aid around a buggy thread isn't workable; the problem is that threads all share the same address space, which means that if one thread is buggy it can (and often will) corrupt the state of all of the other threads as well, eventually causing incorrect behavior, deadlocks, crashes, etc.  The only solution is to go in and fix the underlying bug, or to rewrite the application to use separate processes instead of threads (since each process gets its own memory space, you have some assurance that bugs in process A won't corrupt process B)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the thing is as a user I don't use threads, but the library uses them internally to handle the connections, `; line1 (define ws-executor (make-will-executor))
;line2 (void (thread (lambda () (let loop () (will-execute ws-executor) (loop)))))` the error raises from there, so I guess I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you contact the authors of the library and ask them about it?  Maybe they can help.

Comment: I will, thank you again fren.